# I want to use my Eventbrite account credentials to be able to login in the web app i am developing how do i do it?

Tags: api, authentication, web-applications, eventbrite

I am developing a web application for musicians to grow their fan base for their music.
I want that as a musician if i have a eventbrite account already.
I can directly sign in using the same EventBrite Account Credentials to create an account in my proposed web application.
I did find that Eventbrite provides an API
Link: https://www.eventbrite.com/platform/api
I just want to know will this API help to achieve what i want irrespective of my web app technology stack i am using.
Please help.

Comment: You can use oauth2, have a look here: https://www.eventbrite.com/platform/docs/authentication